# Diagram in Canvas JS specified interval?

Tags: javascript, canvas, canvasjs

The problem I am encountering is that I want a specified interval to be shown in y-axis. Instead of 0 too whatever, I want the Y-axis to only show the interval between 100-250. How can I implement this in the link below I have shared?

[Link to code](http://canvasjs.com/editor/?id=http://canvasjs.com/example/gallery/dynamic/realtime_line/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the y-axis minimum and maximum parameters to define a range:

Docs: [Maximum](http://canvasjs.com/docs/charts/chart-options/axisy/maximum/), [Minimum](http://canvasjs.com/docs/charts/chart-options/axisy/minimum/)

```
 axisY:{
     minimum: 100,
     maximum: 250
 },
```